# Linq to Sql navigation object instance properties are null or default

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm using Linq to Sql and have a proper foreign key relationship setup in the underlying tables.

However, when I try to use navigation properties I have a subtle bug.

In the code sample below, when I put a watch on the PartDetails, I do get the fully populated parts. However, if I call the property on each part to check their values, the instance is now null.

I've hunted around for the last couple of hours to find an answer but so far coming up dry.

Can anyone clue me in as to why this is happening?

I'm on .net 4.6.1, Visual studio 2015 and Sql Server 2014.

I confess I couldn't find the correct place to fire off the DataLoadOptions but this seemed to work fine!

```
Partial Public Class LabourDetail
    Private Sub OnCreated()
        Dim db As New DataContext
        Dim ds As DataLoadOptions = New DataLoadOptions()
        ds.LoadWith(Function(c As LabourDetail) c.PartDetails)
        db.LoadOptions = ds
    End Sub
    Public ReadOnly Property AnyPartsUnConsumed As Boolean
        Get
        'If I put a watch on the partdetails I do get a proper collection with proper instances.
            Return PartDetails.Where(Function(p) p.PartsUnConsumed).Any
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Partial Public Class PartDetail
'When we reach this point, the values in the instance are all Null  / Default
    Public Property PartsUnConsumed() As Boolean = _CheckPartsUnConsumed()
End Class
```

I'd be grateful for any assistance!

Comment: What's the intended purpose of this `OnCreated` method? Whatever it is, presently it does nothing. You create a `db` instance, which is garbage-collected when the method is over.

Comment: @gert arnold - ah thank you- DOH! So that would be a double facepalm right there then? Would you put this as an answer, as your pointing out what should have been obvious to me is the answer and needs an upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `Private Sub OnCreated()` effectively doesn't do anything. It creates a context that immediately goes out of scope.

I assume there is some context that materializes `LabourDetail`s from the database. *That's* the context to set the `LoadOptions` of.

Comment: Thank you for this. I broke my rule, trying to figure things out on a Friday afternoon :)

Comment: I was trying to centralise this because I need the child entities to load in more than one place. Hence the misguided attempt at on created.So far, the ways to do it all feel wrong, including a partial class with a Property as List(of Parts) that is checked and populated if required.